# How to bundle multiple JS files in Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, build

I'm working on an angular application which uses quite **a bit of plugins** and **dependencies**. The problem is that while developing, **each file** is loaded on each load. I want to bundle each of the files into one file when I run the build.

My Angular was manually setup, so I am not using the Angular CLI, the --prod method will not work with the current setup.

See attached image

[image: Network Screen]

Comment: basically, you want to use something like webpack, who actually does tihs job  pretty well (and pretty mysteriously...)

Comment: You can create an `angular-cli`app and run `ng eject` there and it will show you all the webpack configs that it's using, and go from there.